# Create a view in database as migration with Cakephp3

Tags: database, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Does anyone knows how to create a view in database with CakePHP3?
Is there a way to do this with migrations? 
Like define a view to being executed then when I run cake/bin migrations migrate this create view in BD. Than this may create a view and I must be able to execute this view whatever I want in models or controllers?

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: At the very least, migrations will let you directly `execute` any SQL code you want, so you could create the view that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As markstory said in this issues on GitHub this, functionalities didn't exist ye and may be released soon:

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/11632
https://github.com/cakephp/migrations/issues/347